# Enter text into multi stacked donut chart

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm using the `recharts` to render some charts with `PieChart` and `Pie`. It's a multi-stacked donut chart. I want to enter the **label text** in each section of the chart. When I call the label in the `PieChart` then it shows me the numeric values outside the donut-chart. I want to enter the text inside the donut chart.

```
import React from 'react';
import { PieChart, Pie } from 'recharts';

export default function App() {
  const data01 = [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "value": 2400
    },
    {
      "name": "Group B",
      "value": 4567
    },
    {
      "name": "Group C",
      "value": 1398
    },
    {
      "name": "Group D",
      "value": 9800
    },
    {
      "name": "Group E",
      "value": 3908
    },
    {
      "name": "Group F",
      "value": 2000
    }
  ];
  const data02 = [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "value": 1000,
      "fill": "#77D970"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group B",
      "value": 1000,
      "fill": "#77D970"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group C",
      "value": 1000,
      "fill": "#77D970"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group D",
      "value": 1000,
      "fill": "#77D970"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group E",
      "value": 1000,
      "fill": "#77D970"
    },
    {
      "name": "Group F",
      "value": 1000,
      "fill": "#4B6587",
      "uv": "21"
    }
  ];
  const data03 = [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group B",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group C",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group D",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group E",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group F",
      "value": 1000
    }
  ];
  const data04 = [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "value": 1000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Group B",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group C",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group D",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group E",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group F",
      "value": 1000
    }
  ];
  const data05 = [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group B",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group C",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group D",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group E",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group F",
      "value": 1000
    }
  ];
  const data06 = [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "value": 1000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Group B",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group C",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group D",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group E",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Group F",
      "value": 1000
    }
  ];
  const data07 = [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "value": 1000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Group B",
      "value": 1000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Group C",
      "value": 1000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Group D",
      "value": 1000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Group E",
      "value": 1000,
    },
    {
      "name": "Group F",
      "value": 1000,
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <PieChart width={1000} height={800}>
        {/* <Pie data={data01} dataKey="value" nameKey="name" cx="50%" cy="50%" innerRadius={40} outerRadius={60} fill="#8884d8" /> */}
        <Pie data={data02} dataKey="value" nameKey="name" cx="50%" cy="50%" innerRadius={50} outerRadius={70} />
        <Pie data={data03} dataKey="value" nameKey="name" cx="50%" cy="50%" innerRadius={70} outerRadius={90} fill="#77D970" />
        <Pie data={data04} dataKey="value" nameKey="name" cx="50%" cy="50%" innerRadius={90} outerRadius={110} fill="#77D970" />
        <Pie data={data05} dataKey="value" nameKey="name" cx="50%" cy="50%" innerRadius={110} outerRadius={130} fill="#77D970" />
        <Pie data={data06} dataKey="value" nameKey="name" cx="50%" cy="50%" innerRadius={130} outerRadius={150} fill="#D5D5D5" />
        <Pie data={data07} dataKey="value" nameKey="name" cx="50%" cy="50%" innerRadius={150} outerRadius={170} fill="#4B6587" label />
      </PieChart>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my code. It's a multi-stacked Donut Chart.

Answer (score 0):

From the `rechart` [documentation](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Pie#label):

> If false set, labels will not be drawn. If true set, labels will be drawn which have the props calculated internally. If the object is set, labels will be drawn which have the props merged by the internally calculated props and the option. If ReactElement is set, the option can be the custom label element. If set a function, the function will be called to render a customized label.

So, you can pass a custom react component to render with the `label` props:

You can create your own custom label and import it to the `App` component, here is an example:

```
const renderCustomizedLabel = ({ cx, cy, midAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius, percent, index }) => {
  const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.5;
  const x = cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * (Math.PI / 180));
  const y = cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * (Math.PI / 180));

  return (
    <text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor={x > cx ? 'start' : 'end'} dominantBaseline="central">
      {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`}
    </text>
  );
};
```

Now, pass the `renderCustomizedLabel` to the `label` property in the `Pie` element:

```
<Pie
  data={data02} 
  dataKey="value"
  nameKey="name" 
  cx="50%" 
  cy="50%" 
  innerRadius={50}  
  outerRadius={70}
  label={renderCustomizedLabel}
  labelLine={false}
/>
```

**Note:** Also set the `labelLine` to `false` to ignore the drawing a line to show the label.